# I have been trying to create a code to find the Perimeter, Area, Semi-Perimeter etc. But I am stuck on getting the angles

Tags: java

I recently tried converting a Turing program to java, but it hasn't worked out as well as I've planned. Here's the turing program.

```
var rgr, peri, semiperi, area, radcirc, radinsc, angle1, angle2, angle3 : 
real
var nextpage : char
var input1, input2, input3 : int
put " "
put "Input side length a; make sure it's a positive integer. (in centimetres)"
get input1
put "Input side length b; make sure it's a positive integer. (in centimetres)"
get input2
put "Input side length c; make sure it's a positive integer. (in centimetres)"
get input3
% Now here is where the cal-goo-lations are performed
peri := input1 + input2 + input3
semiperi := peri / 2
area := semiperi * (semiperi - input1) * (semiperi - input2) * (semiperi - input3)
radcirc := (input1 * input2 * input3) / (4 * area)
radinsc := (2 * area) / peri
angle1 := arccosd ((input2 ** 2 + input3 ** 2 - input1 ** 2) / (2 * input2 * input3))
angle2 := arccosd ((input3 ** 2 + input1 ** 2 - input2 ** 2) / (2 * input3 * input1))
angle3 := arccosd ((input1 ** 2 + input2 ** 2 - input3 ** 2) / (2 * input1 * input2))
put " "
delay (500)
cls
put "PAGE #1: The Basics"
put " "
put "1. This triangle's perimeter is..."
put peri, " cm"
put " "
put "2. This triangle's semi-perimeter is..."
put semiperi, " cm"
put " "
put "3. This triangle's area is..."
put area, " cm squared"
put " "
delay (500)
cls
put "PAGE #2: Circumscribed/Inscribed Circles"
put " "
put "4. The radius of the circumscribed circle is..."
put radcirc, " cm"
put " "
put "5. The radius of the inscribed circle is..."
put radinsc, " cm"
put " "
delay (500)
cls
put "PAGE #3: Angles"
put " "
put "6. The three angles are..."
put "Angle 1's angle is ", angle1:0:1
put "Angle 2's angle is ", angle2:0:1
put "Angle 3's angle is ", angle3:0:1
put " "
put "Thanks for using this program!"
```

So in the turing program, the angle calculation worked. But, when I tried to convert it to java it wouldn't. Here's my code.

```
import java.lang.Math;
class JavaTriangleCalg00lations
{
public static void main (String[] args)
{
int posInt1, posInt2, posInt3 ;
double peri, sP, area, circumR, inscrR, angle1, angle2, angle3, dposInt1, dposInt2, dposInt3;

System.out.println("Please put in 3 positive integers.");
System.out.println(" ");
do
{
  System.out.println("Enter the 1st integer; positive only.");
  posInt1= In.getInt();
} while (posInt1 <= 0);
{
  do
  {
    System.out.println("Enter the 2nd integer; positive only.");
    posInt2= In.getInt();
  } while (posInt2 <= 0);
}
{
  do
  {
    System.out.println("Enter the 3rd integer; positive only.");
    posInt3= In.getInt();
  } while (posInt3 <= 0);
  System.out.println(" ");

  //ayy yo lmao xD
  dposInt1 = posInt1;
  dposInt2 = posInt2;
  dposInt3 = posInt3;
  peri = posInt1 + posInt2 + posInt3;
  sP = peri / 2;
  area = sP * (sP- posInt1) * (sP - posInt2) * (sP - posInt3);
  circumR = (posInt1 * posInt2 * posInt3) / (4 * area);
  inscrR = (2 * area) / peri;
  angle1 =   Math.toDegrees(Math.acos((dposInt2 * dposInt2) + (dposInt3 * dposInt3)  - (dposInt1 * dposInt1)) / (2 * dposInt2 * dposInt3));
  angle2 =  Math.toDegrees(Math.acos((dposInt3 * dposInt3) + (dposInt1 * dposInt1) - (dposInt2 * dposInt2)) / (2 * dposInt3 * dposInt1));
  angle3 =  Math.toDegrees(Math.acos((dposInt1 * dposInt1) + (dposInt2 * dposInt2) - (dposInt3 * dposInt3)) / (2 * dposInt1 * dposInt2));
}
System.out.print("The Perimeter is... ");
System.out.print(peri);
System.out.print("The Semi-Perimeter is... ");
System.out.print(sP);
System.out.print("The Area is... ");
System.out.print(area);
System.out.print("The circumscribed radius is... ");
System.out.print(circumR);
System.out.print("The inscribed radius is... ");
System.out.print(inscrR);

System.out.println(" ");

System.out.println("The three angles are... ");
System.out.println("Angle 1... ");
System.out.println(Math.round(angle1 * 100) / 100);
System.out.println("Angle 2... ");
System.out.println(Math.round(angle2 * 100) / 100);
System.out.println("Angle 3... ");
System.out.println(Math.round(angle3 * 100) / 100);

System.out.println(" ");

System.out.println("Thanks for using this program!");
}
}
```

And for some reason the numbers were inaccurate. For example; when I entered the integers 6, 8, 10; it said the angles were 90 degrees, 90 degrees, 90 degrees.

Comment: `Math.round(angle1 * 100) / 100` gives you a long. So are losing any decimal places, if that's an issue. I don't know what answer you expect to get though. It would be helpful if you could say what angles you expect for an input of 6,8,10.

Comment: @KarlReid the whole reasoning for that part of the program, were to calculate what the triangle's angles would be when a user inputs side lengths; sorry that my code isn't the most legible on the planet as I'm pretty new to Java and this was my first major error in which I was stumped on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind; I realized after hours of pondering that the error. It was careless use of brackets.

The code that worked was...

```
 angle1 =  Math.toDegrees(Math.acos((dposInt2 * dposInt2 + dposInt3 * dposInt3  - dposInt1 * dposInt1) / (2 * dposInt2 * dposInt3)));
 angle2 =  Math.toDegrees(Math.acos((dposInt3 * dposInt3 + dposInt1 * dposInt1 - dposInt2 * dposInt2) / (2 * dposInt3 * dposInt1)));
 angle3 =  Math.toDegrees(Math.acos((dposInt1 * dposInt1+ dposInt2 * dposInt2 - dposInt3 * dposInt3) / (2 * dposInt1 * dposInt2)));
```

Compared to...

```
 angle1 =  Math.toDegrees(Math.acos((dposInt2 * dposInt2) + (dposInt3 * dposInt3)  - (dposInt1 * dposInt1)) / (2 * dposInt2 * dposInt3));
 angle2 =  Math.toDegrees(Math.acos((dposInt3 * dposInt3) + (dposInt1 * dposInt1) - (dposInt2 * dposInt2)) / (2 * dposInt3 * dposInt1));
 angle3 =  Math.toDegrees(Math.acos((dposInt1 * dposInt1) + (dposInt2 * dposInt2) - (dposInt3 * dposInt3)) / (2 * dposInt1 * dposInt2));
```

Using the example inputs I used previously (6, 8, 10), The angles outputed to 36.86989764584401, 53.13010235415598 and 90; which is as close as it'll get to 180 degrees to complete a triangle. Thanks to those who tried to help me!

Answer (score 0):

To read input from the user through the shell, use the Scanner class.

first step : Important scanner class (goes at top of your program) `import java.util.Scanner;`

Second step : Instantiate scanner `Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);`place at line 5 (above those variable declarations)

Third step : Search and replace. Where you see `In.getIn()` replace with `scanner.nextInt()` or `scanner.nextDouble()` Depending on if the variable is of type int or double

Edit: This was not your question. Please add the formulas you are using to calculate perimeter please, thanks!

Comment: The question is about why the math is incorrect not how to get input from user.

Comment: @Brennan, csm is right, the error isn't about how to get the input, it's about why the math is incorrect.

Comment: I see, my apology